# FlexRaid - how to auto start a storage pool on boot?

Tags: storage, mount, software-raid, pool

When I reboot my windows machine my FlexRaid storage pool drive letter does not automatically appear. I have to open FlexRaid, open the pool and click the Publish / Re-Start button then it appears.

I found documentation that explains steps on how to make a pool auto-start, but I think it may be for version 1.x of flex raid. How do I auto-start / publish a pool in FlexRaid version 2??  (is it the same, if so, where is the config file or screen in v2 the corresponds?)

Comment: So I was told I need to set the auto start delay in preferences - a 0 means it does not auto-start.  I tried setting it to "1" also "1000", click save, no error, but it is not saving that setting.  If I close out and re-open the flexraid admin it is back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little more digging, found a way to get it to work!    Create a file named AutoStart.txt in the flex raid folder and put the autostart value in there  (1000 is what i used).   Now my pool (z drive) mounts at startup!